# Manually setting "in-reply-to" mail header with gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm using the gmail web interface, and I've happened to read an online mailing list archive. I want to reply to a specific message of a user, and I already know its message-id.

To make my reply be in the correct thread, I found I need to to set the in-reply-to header to the message-id of that mail I want to reply to.

Is that possible with gmail? Is it possible with any email program that has a modern GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to do it with Mozilla Thunderbird.

Go to

```
Edit
 -> Preferences

Tab Advanced
  Subtab General
    Button "Config Editor"
```

Then for the setting "mail.compose.other.header", add "In-Reply-To". Then you can choose that header when you compose a message just the way you can choose CC/To and others.

Comment: Gmail???????????????